# Adicionar produtos ao carrinho

Tags: php, javascript

Em um site qualquer, existe uma lista de produtos e esses produtos podem ser adicionados ao carrinho, como eu poderia pegar o id desses produtos no momento do clique do usuário? Eu pensei assim

```
<div class="products">
     <figure>
         <img src="prod_img.png" class="product_image" />
     </figure>
     <h3 class="product_name">Produto X</h3>
     <span class="product_price">R$ 99,90</span>
     <input type="submit" productId="xxxx" class="button-add" value="Adicionar ao carrinho" />
</div>
```

Quando o usuário clica no botão 'Adicionar ao carrinho', o javascript irá pegar a id do produto contida dentro do atributo **productId** e enviar ao php para que ele possa adicionar o produto ao carrinho e retornar o produto já adicionado (Em ajax). Eu também poderia criar o carrinho puramente em javascript, adicionando os dados em um **document.cookie**  e percorrer a div 'products' para pegar a imagem, o nome, o preço e o id do produto e adicionar no carrinho, quando o usuário submeter a compra, o id será usado como referência ao produto que será resgatado do banco de dados com php. Isso é dúvida de iniciante, mas, essas soluções são utilizadas no dia-a-dia? Ou é só uma gambiarra? Qual o melhor método para isso?

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é que você faça uma requisição ajax, enviando o id do produto para ser adicionado em uma tabela relacional vinculando o id do produto ao seu carrinho, no banco de dados.

Dessa forma você pode sair e entrar do site e seu carrinho estará lá com o produto. Muitos sites inclusive utilizam essa informação para enviar e-mails dizendo que você esqueceu algo no seu carrinho e perguntando se não quer prosseguir com a compra.

Portanto a ideia de armazenar em javascript, ou cookie não seria adequada.

Quando ao seu html, eu trocaria o input type submit para um input type button, pois o submit é pra ser utilizado dentro de formulários em requisições sincronas comuns (com o "refresh" da pagina).

Existem diversas formas de organizar isso, pense sempre na forma mais semântica (entendivel para quem nunca mexeu no seu codigo) e mais escalável (organizado, com funções bem definidas e sem codigos duplicados).

Comment: Obrigado por tirar minha dúvida e me der essa dica do input 'submit', eu não tenho muita experiência com front.